# You shouldn't be able to suggest a tag as a synonym of itself

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Suggesting a tag as a synonym of itself is just silly and shouldn't be allowed.

On a related note, some moderator could remove the [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=methods&sort=info) `[methods]` -> `[methods]` synonym (or a few people could downvote it).

Comment: Not even the `[recursion]` tag?

Comment: @David: I stand corrected.

Comment: My downvote (to put it at -3) on the `[methods]` synonym auto-nuked it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestTheSameUserShouldNotBeAllowedToProposeAndVote() {
        var user = GetEditor();
        var synonym = TagSynonym.ProposeSynonym(user, "abcdefg", "f-sharpx");
        ShouldRaiseException<InvalidVoteException>(() => synonym.Upvote(user));
    }
```

This is done.

Comment: You do realize that Jeff owns [another website](http://www.codinghorror.com), right? ;)

Comment: @Jon I kind of did this on purpose, but the purpose was misguided :)