# Self referencing synonym

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms

Today I accidentally created a self referencing synonym ended up crashing that tag's page until I found a way to remove it. My procedure was:

- Propose that Y map to existing tag X using the standard synonym suggestion interface.
- Merge X into Y (including checking that box at the bottom) of the moderator tag merging system.
- Go to the full synonym list and approve the suggested synonym from before, only now it was a self referencing synonym.
- I and other users then couldn't get to the page /questions/tagged/Y (a redirect loop error).

The issue was resolved when I removed the self referencing tag from the main synonym page.

I know that this isn't likely to happen often, but perhaps something should be in place to prevent it just in case.

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58131/you-shouldnt-be-able-to-suggest-a-tag-as-a-synonym-of-itself

Comment: So, really, [tag:recursion] should be a synonym for [tag:recursion].

Comment: @ValetTree http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58131/you-shouldnt-be-able-to-suggest-a-tag-as-a-synonym-of-itself#comment137894_58131